# Direct to another folder with .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cdn

Lets say my folder structure looks like this

```
someproject/v5/.htaccess
someproject/5.0.1/lib.js
someproject/5.0.1/assets/img/png/anotherfolder/helloworld.png
someproject/5.0.2/lib.js
someproject/5.0.2/assets/img/png/anotherfolder/helloworld.png
```

When user enters url's like (and lets say I am the owner of google.com):

```
www.google.com/someproject/v5/lib.js
www.google.com/someproject/v5/assets/img/png/anotherfolder/helloworld.png
```

I want him to be redirected to version i want using the .htaccess file, example if i want to serve version 5.0.1, then the user will be redirected to this:

```
www.google.com/someproject/5.0.1/lib.js
www.google.com/someproject/5.0.1/assets/img/png/anotherfolder/helloworld.png
```

Only one thing may change the version number, this does not work (.htaccess file content):

```
AddType application/javascript .js
AddType text/css .css

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) "https://google.com/release/theme/5.0.1/$1/$2" [R=302,L]
```

How can I make it only change v5 with my version number (syntax) ?

Comment: What is the question? “Any suggestions and critics […]” would be better suited at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I changed the last line :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/v5/(.*)$     "$1/5.0.1/$2" [R=302,L]
```

Your rule did not tell `RewriteRule` to cut out "/v5/".